# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS: SSH fails with `sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation`

Tags: ssh, 22.04, gnome-keyring, ssh-agent

I think my question is going to illustrate that I don't understand the relationship between `ssh`, `ssh-agent`, and `gnome-keyring`, but I've tried all of the fixes suggested in response to similar questions and I'm still getting behavior I don't expect.

I have two keypairs in my `~/.ssh` directory, a 2048 bit RSA key and a ED25519 key. I believe the `~/.ssh` directory and the key files have the correct permissions:

```
drwx------  2 tcquinn tcquinn 4096 Feb 23 11:00 .
-rw-------  1 tcquinn tcquinn  484 Dec  8 14:24 id_ed25519
-rw-r--r--  1 tcquinn tcquinn  113 Dec  8 14:24 id_ed25519.pub
-rw-------  1 tcquinn tcquinn 1852 Dec 10 09:15 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 tcquinn tcquinn  398 Jul 16  2020 id_rsa.pub
```

When I boot into the OS (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS), both keys are already added to `ssh-agent`, at least in the sense that `ssh-add -l` and `ssh-add -L` display information for both keys.

However, when I attempt to `ssh` to a machine that has only the RSA key in its `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, I get the message

```
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for RSA "/home/[USERNAME]/.ssh/id_rsa" from agent: agent refused operation
```

and then I get prompted for my password (which I don't want to use).

Because the RSA key is already added to `ssh-agent`, I would expect to be logged in without further prompting.

Some of the answers to similar questions suggest completely removing `gnome-keyring` from the system, which seems...drastic?

In case it's relevant:

(1) If I watch the `systemctl` logs with `journalctl -f`, at the moment I try to `ssh`, I see the message:

```
Feb 28 17:34:47 [MACHINE_NAME] gnome-keyring-daemon[2099]: the /usr/bin/ssh-add command failed: Child process exited with code 1
```

(2) If I ask for verbose output from `ssh` with `ssh -vvv`, the relevant snippet of the output appears to be:

```
debug1: Offering public key: /home/[USERNAME]/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:[HASH] agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/[USERNAME]/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:[HASH] agent
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: using publickey with RSA SHA256:[HASH]
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:[HASH]
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for RSA "/home/[USERNAME]/.ssh/id_rsa" from agent: agent refused operation
```

(3) If I then "manually" add the keys to `ssh-agent` using `ssh-add` (with no arguments), I get prompted for the passphrase on the keys, it successfully adds both of them, and I can then `ssh` without being prompted for a password, as expected.

(4) Immediately after boot, if I attempt to `ssh` to a machine that has the ED25519 key in its `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, it connects without prompting for a password, as expected.

Comment: I wonder if gnome-keyring has saved an old / incorrect passphrase for the key?

Comment: @steeldriver Entirely possible! But it doesn't seem to get updated when I then "manually" add the keys using `ssh-add` (perhaps because this updates the passphrase in `ssh-agent` but not in `gnome-keyring`? Or something?) You can see that I don't really understand how `ssh-agent` and `gnome-keyring` work together.

Comment: You and me both! There's some info on archwiki that suggest you can [flush](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GNOME/Keyring#Flushing_passphrases) passphrases and then re-add them with seahorse's `ssh-askpass` (although the path on Ubuntu appears to be `/usr/libexec/seahorse/ssh-askpass`)